# Is Ashley Schaeffer from Eastbound and Down modelled on Ric Flair

Tags: character, eastbound-and-down

The outrageous character Ashley Schaeffer (played by Will Ferrell) from the excellent Eastbound And Down series seems to not only look like Ric Flair but also copy some of his mannerisms, like the famous "Woo" that is used to punctuate his sentences. Is there any evidence that this is true?

Videos for comparison:

- [Ashley Schaeffer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zPBb2W9GQAg&feature=related)
- [Ric Flair](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3J8HC-sxiaY)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Series co-creator Ben Best plays Clegg, Kenny’s confidant and drug dealer, and Sylvia Jefferies is Tracy, a coke-sniffing drunk who becomes Kenny’s sort-of girlfriend.
>   Of course, Kenny wants to get back to the major leagues, or at least make some money off his notoriety. To that end, he approaches BMW salesman **Ashley Schaeffer**, **played by Ferrell in full Ric Flair mode** – bleach blonde hair, sunglasses and suits with no socks.

The full article [here](http://www.bullz-eye.com/television_reviews/2009/eastbound_and_down_1.htm).

There's a forum conversation [here](http://wfigs.proboards.com/index.cgi?action=display&board=prowrestling&thread=124232&page=1) that seems to have your same doubts.